# Automation of IE using VBscript 0x80010108 - unknown exception

Tags: internet-explorer, exception, vbscript

I'm trying to click on a button on a webpage using VBScript. The rest of my script works just fine. But at different instances of using the browser object I get an exception. The same code works on another script for a different website.

Here's my code:

```
Set browser = OpenBrowser(strURL)
If Not (browser.document.GetElementByID("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit") Is Nothing) Then
        browser.document.GetElementByID("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit").Click
Else
    MsgBox "Submit button Click failed"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Function OpenBrowser(URL)
Dim ie
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate2 URL
WaitForBrowserReadyStatus(ie)
Set OpenBrowser = ie

End Function

Private Sub WaitForBrowserReadyStatus(ie)
Const WAIT_TIMEOUT = 2000

While (ie.Busy) or (ie.ReadyState <> 4) 

    WScript.Sleep(WAIT_TIMEOUT)
  '    wait (1)
Wend
End Sub
```

I get the error:

> 0x80010108 - unknown exception

either at:

```
If Not (browser.document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit") Is Nothing) Then
```

or at:

```
While (ie.Busy) or (ie.ReadyState <> 4)
```

This exact code works on another VBScript for a different website so I have no idea why it throws these exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

`GetElementByID()` can be tricky. If it finds the element, everything works fine and you can assign the object reference to a variable. But if it *doesn't* find the element, VBScript will throw an `"Object Required"` error when trying to perform an object assignment or object comparison (e.g., `Is Nothing`).

The trick is to use `IsObject()` to test if the value returned is truly an object. If so, perform the object assignment or carry on otherwise as normal.

```
If IsObject(browser.Document.getElementByID("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit")) Then

    ' Object returned. ID was found in the DOM. Safe to assign.
    Dim e
    Set e = browser.Document.getElementByID("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit")
    e.Click

Else

    ' Not an object. In other words, the ID wasn't found in the DOM.

End If
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an 0x800706b5 - unknown exception at the If statement.

Comment: Okay the code that I originally posted works for other sites but not the webpage I need. Is it because the webpage I'm trying to use is an internal webform?